# How to change only a Letter in Column with JS (SP2013)

Tags: javascript, css

I´m using a Custom List for our Shift Schedule and i´m coloring some Words for a better Overview:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Holiday'), td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Gleitzeit')");
$Text.css({"color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"});
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Illness')");
$Text.css({"color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"});
});

</script>
```

This is working fine for me. (I Think it´s possible to combine Holiday and Illness, but i don´t know how)

I also have the Oncall Shift "Oncall (O)" and i´m trying to only bold the **(O)**.
But i have no Idea how i have to change my Code:

```
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('(O)')");
$Text.css({"color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"});
```

In this Case the whole cell is Bold **Onall (O)**

Do you have any Ideas for me to change only the (O) in the cell?

Comment: The strategy should be parse the table or the item which contains the Cell then you should perform changes over the Character
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28476761/How-to-parse-the-inner-html-of-a-data-cell-using-Java-Script.html

Answer (score 0):

Get the content (html) from your cell, replace the `(O)` with something bold...
i.e. insert in your code (*untested!*):

```
var html = $Text.html();
html = html.replace('(O)', '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">(O)</span>'
$Text.html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make use of JSLink's postRedering method. That way it should work for paged data. Here's an example (tested :-))

```
//Namespace: SharePoint Stack Exchange
var SSE = SSE || {};
SSE.ShiftScheduleView = (function () {
    return {
        formatText: function (ctx) {
            var pattern = /Holiday|Gleitzeit|Illness|(\(O\))/ig;

            $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2").each(function () {
                var html = $(this).html();
                html = html.replace(pattern, function replacer(match) {
                    return '<strong style="color: red">' + match + '</strong>';
                });
                $(this).html(html);
            });
        }
    };
})();

//This function registers our JS with the view rendering.
(function () {
    var templateOverrideInfo = {};
    templateOverrideInfo.Templates = {};

    //This registers our JS to run after the view has been rendered. 
    templateOverrideInfo.Templates.OnPostRender = SSE.ShiftScheduleView.formatText;

    //Specify View & ListTemplated Id  that you want to target.
    templateOverrideInfo.BaseViewID = 1;
    templateOverrideInfo.ListTemplateType = 100;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(templateOverrideInfo);
})();
```

Comment: thank you very much. This is working fine! is there a way to color an other pattern in Blue. For Example: |Homeoffice| should be colored in lightblue (not in red).

Comment: I would suggest create another function that takes string parameter and return css-safe string, then instead of returning <strong style=...></strong> code above, return something like <span class="shift-sch [css-safe-string-based-on-matched-str]"> + match + </span>. You can then handle style sheet separately.

CSS would be something like:
span.shift-sch { font-weight: bold }
span.shift-sch.holiday, span.shift-sch.illness { color: red; } 
span.shift-sch.homeoffice{ color: blue; }